# Splitting year of a movie from movie title column

Tags: python, string, split

[image]

I am working with the movie lens data set for recommendation system. I want to split the year of the movie from the title column and put it in a new feature called Year.

```
import re
title = df3.title
df3.Year = re.findall('[(...)]', title)
```

title
Dangerous Minds (1995)
Sleepers (1996)
Cinema Paradiso (Nuovo cinema Paradiso) (1989)

Comment: Will the year always be at the end? Will there possibly be other things in the title that could be mistaken for a year? Is it possible the year won't be there at all? Your specification (like all specifications) is just a *starting* point :-)

Comment: Yes, there is year at the end of every movie title and there is a year given for every movie. However, there are some observations given like the following:Seven (a.k.a. Se7en) (1995) ; Brothers McMullen, The (1995)

Comment: That should be fine, you just need a regex search at the end of the string for something like `(\d+)` - check out @donkopotamus' answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming it is always at the end of the string:

```
rgx = re.compile(r"(?:\((\d{4})\))?\s*$")
match = rgx.search(txt)

# group 1 will be None if not matched else eg '1989'
year = match.group(1)
```

Comment: TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-65443ebb265e> in <module>()
      1 rgx = re.compile(r"(?:\((\d{4})\))?\s*$")
----> 2 match = rgx.search(df3.title)
      3 
      4 # group 1 will be None if not matched else eg '1989'
      5 year = match.group(1)

TypeError: expected string or buffer

Comment: Do I use df3.title in rgx.search?

Comment: @Che It would seem that df3.title is not a string ... that's up to you to work out

Answer (score -1):

```
expr = re.compile('\((....)\)')
df3.Year = re.findall(expr, title)[-1]
```

Comment: I am getting the following errorTypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-3f924477a138> in <module>()
      1 expr = re.compile('\((....)\)')
----> 2 df3.Year = re.findall(expr, title)[-1]<br>Anaconda2\lib\re.pyc in findall(pattern, string, flags)179 
    180     Empty matches are included in the result."""
--> 181     return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
    182 
    183 if sys.hexversion >= 0x02020000:

TypeError: expected string or buffer

Comment: Your code has mistranscribed the answer. '((....))' is not the same regular expression as the one given, and it looks like you're calling findall on the return value from compile.